# Display dynamically created text box on dynamically created radio button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving some data via json and based on the inputs I have dynamically created a table that displays pre-selected radio buttons (Green / Yellow / Red) based on the values in the input. In the third column, I am displaying a comments box.

Now, I only want to display the comment box only if yellow / red radio button comes as input or if I select.

Here is my code in use:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var appStatus = [{
  "category": "Overall Status",
  "status": "0"
 }, {
  "category": "System Availability",
  "status": "1"
 }, {
  "category": "Whatever",
  "status": "2"
 }];
 var tr;
 for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
   tr = $('<tr/>');
   tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
   tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="0" id="inlineRadio0"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '0' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="black">Grey &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" id="inlineRadio1"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '1' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '2' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '3' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
   //tr.append("<td>" + "<input>" + appStatus[i].comments + "</input>" + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td>" + '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" id="appStatus[i].comments" name="appStatus[i].comments" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control name_list" required' + "</td>");
   $('table').append(tr); }


 $('#result').on('click', function() {
  var new_status = [];
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
   new_status.push({
    category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()
   });
  });

  console.log(new_status);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add handlers to each radio input. Since you are using jQuery, the attached event handlers have `this` as the event source. You must separate your longer `<tr>...</tr>` blocks in order to achieve this.

A simple example:

```
table.append('<tr/>').append(
    $('<td>').append(
        $('<input type="radio" name="x">').change(function () {
            $(this).closest('td').find('input.comments').toggle(true or false);
        })
    )
)
```

...but you can be smarter and write this much clearer using variables.

There's also that you are appending `<tr>` elements inside another in your code, which leads to invalid HTML. Plus some other small glitches that need to be worked on.

Comment: Couldn't help me. Is there a way to update hidden="true"  to hidden="false" within the javascript while changing the radio-buttons. I added that to the last tr.append for input text box.

Comment: Yes, but you must really start by studying your HTML and CSS well. *Start* by writing out what you want to achieve in HTML *by hand*, then make it to a script; you will find a way. There are many basic errors in your code, but fortunately there are many resources available on the net.